# MySQL GROUP BY rand()?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, interesting problem I've run into. I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I'm not sure what it is. :)

Basically, imagine a very simple database, like so:

```
----------------
T1
----------------
  r  |  nID
---------------
  1  |   A
  2  |   B
----------------




----------------
T2
----------------
 nID |  val
---------------
  A  |   XXX
  B  |   L
  B  |   M
  B  |   N
  B  |   P
----------------
```

Basically, Table 2 references Table 1. Now, I'd like to select a random row from either A or B. However, I would like to first randomize the A and B, THEN choose an associated value.

In other words, flip a coin: Heads, `XXX`. Tails, `L, M, N,` or `P`.

My current query joins the two tables, orders by `RAND()`, and then `LIMIT 1`. However, this makes the odds of a B value being chosen much more likely than an A value being chosen. I'm using PHP, so I could easily just run two queries, but running one query would be much tidier, so I want to see what you guys recommend.

Any solutions? =)

## EDIT:

Here's my current query, but it isn't working. Not sure why!

```
SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE
    nID =
    (
        SELECT nID
        FROM t1
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

## EDIT 2:

To demonstrate the issue I'm having, I created a test case. First, I created the following tables:

[image: T1 and T2]

I want the odds of selecting `XXX` to be identical to selecting `L`, `M`, `N`, or `P`. The query I have should do it, right? So I tested it. The followings script runs the query 5000 times, and counts the results. They should be about 50-50, with `XXX` showing up approximately 2500 times, and everything else showing up about 2500 times as well.

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$i = 0;
while ($i < 5000)
{
    $query = mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM t2
        WHERE
            nID =
            (
                SELECT nID
                FROM t1
                ORDER BY RAND()
                LIMIT 1
            )
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
        ") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if ($result['val'] == 'XXX')
    {
        $a++;
    }
    else
    {
        $b++;
    }

    $i++;
}

echo "XXX - $a<br />";
echo "Other - $b<br />";
```

Here are the results:

```
XXX - 937
Other - 4063
```

Let's run it again.

```
XXX - 968
Other - 4032
```

And let's run it one more time.

```
XXX - 932
Other - 4068
```

This is hardly the 50-50 split we'd expect to see given my query. What on earth's going on? Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: can u try randomizing using mt_rand in php?. Assuming it might give better random values?

Comment: I want to do this entirely in MySQL. The disproportional distribution of results is because there are less A values than B values.

Comment: I ran a test case to demonstrate. See above. ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would expect that the subquery in your question would be run once per outer query, but it looks like that's not the case. I think the below might give you what you're after:

```
SET @randID = (SELECT nID
FROM T1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1);

SELECT VAL
FROM T2
WHERE nID = @randID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

[(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1e8/12)

Comment: Though Joachim Isaksson's solution is arguably more elegant, I actually like this solution more. It's easier to understand at a quick glance, whereas J.I.'s is less intuitive. Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your example inner query is evaluated multiple times, if you want it to choose A or B *once*, you need to rewrite it, for example as a `JOIN`;

```
SELECT q2.nID, q2.val
FROM ( SELECT nID FROM T1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) q1
JOIN T2 q2 ON q1.nID = q2.nID
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

If you're working with small tables, this query should be ok, but read [here for example](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/) on why you shouldn't use `ORDER BY RAND()` for large tables.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2921/19).

Answer (score 1):

Please try query given below

```
SELECT `table2`.*  FROM `table2` WHERE table2.field1 = (Select table1.field2 from table1 order by RAND() limit 0,1) LIMIT 0,1
```

Here i assume column name field1 and field2 for both table so please use field name according your table structure.

thanks

Comment: See my edited query. It still doesn't appear to be working. :/

Comment: Though this solution did not work, it helped get me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE rq.r WHEN '1' THEN t1q.r ELSE t2q.nID END AS Col1,
    CASE rq.r WHEN '1' THEN t1q.nID ELSE t2q.val END AS Col2
FROM
    (SELECT CASE WHEN RAND() < 0.5 THEN '1' ELSE '2' END AS r) AS rq
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as t1q
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM T2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as t2q
```

Observation: This query is inefficient because it requires selecting a random row from both tables even though only one is used. Perhaps a better way exists.

Comment: I don't understand this query, so I don't know how to implement it into what I currently have. Can you explain, and perhaps modify the table / column names to match the example I have above?